# Mongoose best practices for document creation with unknown number of items in a field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I've looked around left and right, I wrote some demo code, wrote some tests to implement a school management system.

What I want to know from people more used to mongoose development is how would be the best practice to create this schema in a way that made it possible to add as many address, and contact fees as I want from this single document.

I made my own solution, but I don't know if it is the most elegant and feasible way, I want an opinion from seasoned people.

Should I create separate models for address, email and phone numbers?

I created this schema. It still has some pseudo-code, but for giving the general idea is fine.

```
var student = {
    name: String, 
    surname: String, 
    currentClass: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: "Classes"
    }, 
    birthday: {
        year: Number,
        month: Number,
        day: Number
    },
    address: [{
        name: String, 
        zip: Number,
        address: String, 
        city: String, 
        state: String, 
        complement: String
    }]
    accountable: {
        name: String, 
        surname: String, 
        email: [{
            type: String, 
            required: true, 
            lowercase: true
        }], 
    phone: [String, String]
}
```

My sollution was, by using html, creating a new "email" or "address" fields as the user requested by clickinking in the propper button. This generated a new input field with a name that followed a pattern like:
email1, email2, email3, email4

And so, when the user sent the data, if we were creating a new student I would first create the array with the data and send it to mongoose.

In case of updating, I would get the already created emails and add it to the new array with the `newEmails.concat(old_emails)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To design the database, there are many situations for it:
1 to 1, 1 to many, many to many.
**One to one**: you should to put the strong object inside the other, for example:
a person can have only one passport, then we should put passport object inside the person object.
**One to Many**, 3 cases for one to many.
**One to Few**:few is less than 100 objects,Then you should add the few as list in the one object, for example:
A person can have multiple addresses as in your example above.
**One to Many**:many is Thousands, then you should put the primary keys  of the many in a list inside the the one object.
**One to Too many**: then do not do the previous solution, but instead add the primary of the one in every objects of the many.
And finally, **Many to Many**: you should put them as list in both sides.
Check the below references:
https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1
https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-2
https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-3

Morover, for this part `phone: [String, String]`, you should make it `phone: [String]`

Comment: Thanks a lot... at the time I was fairly new to mongoose and data modeling. I used one to few for address and telephone numbers,...
I also changed the front-end, swapping express template engines for angular...
Now, reworking the angular side of things again, to update to angular 2/4.